# Proguard can't find referenced class, jar was made by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, proguard, obfuscation

I have a project that has referenced libraries (which is Apache POI). So in Eclipse, Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add External JARs and I included 4 jars from the library (poi, poi-ooxml, poi-ooxml-schemas, xmlbeans)

When I build my jar, I chose File -> Export, Runnable JAR file, Extract required libraries into generated JAR. I have verified that this unobfuscated jar works fine.

In Proguard GUI, I added the input file (the JAR produced by Eclipse) and the output file where I want the output to be saved.

Since it's a javaFX project and uses javax.crypto library, I have to add library jars in the Proguard manually too: jfxrt.jar and jce.jar. Here is potentially the problem. Maybe I need to add the jars from the Apache POI library too? But doing this gives me 'duplicate definition of library class ...' warning and does not resolve the can't find referenced class warning.

I have tried ignoring the warnings, but the obfuscated JAR does not function.

There are really a lot of warnings, but here are the first five:

```
Note: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.jam.internal.reflect.ReflectClassBuilder calls 'Field.getType'
Warning: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.jam.internal.javadoc.JavadocRunner: can't find superclass or interface com.sun.javadoc.Doclet
Warning: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MatchingTask
Warning: com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.CTClientData: can't find referenced class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.STCF
Warning: com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.CTClientData: can't find referenced class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.STCF
```

What is and how to solve this problem so that I can obfuscate my JAR?

EDIT:

here are the last lines of Proguard's processing console:

```
      Maybe this is program field 'org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STThemeColor$Enum { org.apache.xmlbeans.StringEnumAbstractBase$Table table; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STUnderline$Enum { org.apache.xmlbeans.StringEnumAbstractBase$Table table; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STVerticalAlignRun$Enum { org.apache.xmlbeans.StringEnumAbstractBase$Table table; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STVerticalJc$Enum { org.apache.xmlbeans.StringEnumAbstractBase$Table table; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STZoom$Enum { org.apache.xmlbeans.StringEnumAbstractBase$Table table; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'org.openxmlformats.schemas.xpackage.x2006.relationships.STTargetMode$Enum { org.apache.xmlbeans.StringEnumAbstractBase$Table table; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets { char[][] table; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI { javax.swing.JTable table; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'javax.swing.table.JTableHeader { javax.swing.JTable table; }'
Note: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl accesses a field 'typeSystem' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.s0B482D0B338CC9641C1543C3510577FE.TypeSystemHolder { org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeSystem typeSystem; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sF1327CCA741569E70F9CA8C9AF9B44B2.TypeSystemHolder { org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeSystem typeSystem; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sXMLCONFIG.TypeSystemHolder { org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeSystem typeSystem; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sXMLLANG.TypeSystemHolder { org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeSystem typeSystem; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sXMLSCHEMA.TypeSystemHolder { org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeSystem typeSystem; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sXMLTOOLS.TypeSystemHolder { org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeSystem typeSystem; }'
Note: there were 1 classes trying to access generic signatures using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the signature attributes
      (using '-keepattributes Signature').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 14 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Note: there were 2 class casts of dynamically created class instances.
      You might consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes and/or
      their implementations (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclasscast)
Note: there were 12 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
      (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)
Warning: there were 13088 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 7 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Please correct the above warnings first.
```